# LU Decopmostions with block

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

So both $A_{11}$ and $\hat{A_{22}}$ have $LU$ decompositions say $A_{11}=L_{1}U_{1}$ and $\hat{A_{22}}=L_{2}U_{2}$. Show that
 $ \begin{bmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} L_1 & 0 \\ ML_1 & L_2 \end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix} U_{1} & L^{-1}_{1}A_{12} \\ 0 & U_{2} \end{bmatrix}$ .
Show that this is LU decomposition of $A$. 
Here is my attempt at the problem if we mutpliy the matrix out we get
 $ \begin{bmatrix} L_{1}U_{1} & A_{12} \\ ML_1U_1 & ML_1L_{1}^{-1}A_{12}+L_2U_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} \end{bmatrix} $
Note that $\hat{A_{22}}$ = $ A_{22} - A_{21}A{_{11}}^{-1}A_{12}$
Im not sure if im doing this right what. What do I have to show that this is the  LU decomposition of $A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume all the inverses used exist, and the sizes of the matrices make the products possible.

---

We have to show that the corresponding entries in the matrices are equal.

1. For $A_{11}$: Follows directly from assumptions
2. For $A_{21}$: Is $M = A_{21}A_{11}^{-1}$?

If so, then

$$ML_1U_1 = MA_{11} = A_{21}A_{11}^{-1}A_{11} = A_{21}$$

3. For $A_{22}$: Again, is $M = A_{21}A_{11}^{-1}$?

If so, by noting other assumption, we have

$MA_{12} + L_2U_2 = A_{21}A_{11}^{-1}A_{12} + A_{22} - A_{21}A_{11}^{-1}A_{12} = A_{22}$